# How can I successfully ask a question in Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, asking-questions

It's weird; I have asked a few questions on this website, but when I login, they're all gone. What's wrong? What should I do to post successfully? Any guidance?

Answer (score 19):

You didn't ask questions; you posted an [advertisement](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/5baeb6d565869d7019bffaf1b8a22409). Such posts are considered [spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/295232) and quickly removed by joint effort of the community. If you want to advertise on Stack Exchange, please use the [recommended channels](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising) to do so.

Comment: Also his SO profile reads like advertisement.